# DevExpress data bound TextBox clears/reverts value

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, devexpress, textedit

I have a form with some data bound DevExpress TextEdits. I find it really strange that if I change the value and then change the focus to some other control, after a few seconds the value reverts to the first value when the form was loaded. I can't understand why this is happening..

The textedit is bound as follows:

`textEdit_name.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", person, "Name", true));`

I have other textboxes bound in the same way, but there are no problems with them.

EDIT: It's the same if I use a normal winforms textbox, instead of DevExpress.

Comment: Try adding 
new Binding("Text", person, "Name", true,  DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged );

Worth trying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `DevExpress` editors you must bind to [`BaseEdit.EditValue`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/DevExpressXtraEditorsBaseEdit_EditValuetopic) property instead of `Text` property:

```
textEdit_name.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("EditValue", person, "Name", true));
```